# Wordpress wp_query post_type and taxonomy not works

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to get posts, with custom post type and taxonomy. I tried with this codes:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'specification',
   'tax_query' => array(
        array(
'           taxonomy' => 'model',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'term' => 'grand-cherokee-2013'
        )
    ),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and:

```
global $wp_query;
query_posts( array(  
    'post_type' => 'specification',
    'category_name' => 'model',
    'showposts' => '10' ) 
);
```

I did print_r($wp_query), request was:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND 0 = 1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'specification' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Why wordpress adds 0 = 1? I think problem is here. How i can solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

$caledar_custom_detail=get_term( $c, 'calendar_category' ); // $c for category id and custom category type

```
$current_slug = $caledar_custom_detail->slug;
$post_query_loop_value=query_posts( array( 'calendar_category' => $current_slug, 'showposts' => 3 ) );
```

In array first, the parameter 'calendor_category' means custom category type
$current_slug means category slug
'showposts' for how many post u want to display.

If not getting desired output let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
   'tax_query' => array(
        array(
'           taxonomy' => 'specification',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'term' => 'grand-cherokee-2013'
        )
    ),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I think the problem is that you're setting the taxonomy to 'model' when what you want is 'specification' type.